# If $12$ balls are drawn from a bag with $22$ red balls and $19$ green balls, determine the probability that at least $8$ drawn out are red?

Tags: probability

In $1$ bag there are $22$ red balls and $19$ green balls. Answer this.

If $12$ balls are drawn from the bag, determine the probability that *at least* $8$ drawn out are red? You are to assume that each ball is returned to the bag after each draw. Show appropriate calculation to support your answer.

Comment: this is a homework problem. what have you tried ?

Comment: No, it is for an assignment, problem solving question

Comment: I'm just really stuck and don't know how to work out using calculations

Comment: The two (assignment & homework) are considered the same. Given it's an item of assessment, it's a good idea to show some effort and research!

Comment: Can you compute the probability that exactly $8$ red ones are drawn?

Comment: Yes lulu, you just need at least 8

Comment: Can you show us your answer for exactly $8$?

Comment: 22C8x19C4/41C12=30,985,713/197,466,373 or .1569 + 22C9x19C3/41C12 + 22C10x19C2/41C12 + 22C11x19C1/41C12 + 22C12x19C0/41C12, then add all probabilities together

Comment: That is extremely hard to read.  For exactly $8$ the answer is $\binom {12}8\times p^8\times(1-p)^4$ where $p=\frac {22}{41}$ is the probability that a given ball is red.  Not sure what you are computing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you need to choose the order that you draw the x red balls.

You have ${12\choose x}$ different orders to draw x red balls from the bag.

In each draw, you have a $\frac{22}{41}$ chance to draw a red ball and $\frac{19}{41}$ to draw a blue ball.

So the probability to choose x red balls is ${12\choose x}\times (\frac{22}{41})^{x}\times (\frac{19}{41})^{12-x}$

So, $P$ (at least 8 red balls) = $\sum_{i=8}^{12}{12\choose i}\times (\frac{22}{41})^{i}\times (\frac{19}{41})^{12-i}$

Comment: This would appear to assume that the balls are drawn without replacement.

Comment: @lulu you are right. i'll fix that. thanks

Comment: @lulu just fixed it

Comment: Looks good (+1).